# Socket connected Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://example.com/sockets/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=tTV9_FK1ccrgEsykAAAM

Tags: reactjs, heroku, websocket, socket.io, fastapi

I have a fastapi backend server that uses python-socketio deployed on heroku and a front-end application thats uses react with socektio deployed on netlify. When I go to my websites url, it always disconnects, connects a lot of times and then connects and then again disconnects. Why does this occur?

```
import socketio
from . import main

sio = socketio.AsyncServer(async_mode='asgi', cors_allowed_origins=[])


sio_app = socketio.ASGIApp(socketio_server=sio, socketio_path='/sockets')


rooms = {}


drawingData = {}


@sio.event
async def connect(sid, environ):
    print(sid, 'backend connected')

React component:

@sio.event
async def disconnect(sid):
    print(sid, 'backend disconnected')
# Remove the disconnected user from all rooms
    for room, users in rooms.items():
        if sid in users:
            users.remove(sid)
        # Notify other users in the room about the user leaving
            await sio.emit('user_left', sid, room=room)


import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACK_END_URL}`, { path: '/sockets', origins: "*" });

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Socket connected');
});

socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
  console.log('Socket disconnected', reason);
});

export default socket
```

I tried using "*" origins and this problem does not occur on localhost.